# Arduino Yun HttpClient Example malfunction

Tags: arduino

This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow, so please excuse/point out ways I have transgressed in formatting this question, and I will try to do better next time. I am running the HttpClient example from what I believe is the "Bridge" library on my Yun. Instead of printing out ASCII like it is supposed to, it prints this:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code that is running:

```
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <HttpClient.h>

void setup() {
  // Bridge takes about two seconds to start up
  // it can be helpful to use the on-board LED
  // as an indicator for when it has initialized
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  Bridge.begin();
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

  SerialUSB.begin(9600);

  while (!SerialUSB); // wait for a serial connection
}

void loop() {
  // Initialize the client library
  HttpClient client;

  // Make a HTTP request:
  client.get("http://www.arduino.cc/asciilogo.txt");

  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    SerialUSB.print(c);
  }
  SerialUSB.flush();

  delay(5000);
}
```

I believe my Yun is properly connected to my Wifi network but I know very little about how it works or how the HTML gets processed, so any sort of explanation would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
client.get("http://www.arduino.cc/asciilogo.txt");
```

Into

```
client.get("http://arduino.cc/asciilogo.txt");
```